# How to subscribe to routed event from grandchild in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to handle a bubbling event from a child of a child.  It works in the code behind like this:

```
    public SchedulingBaseView(SchedulingBaseViewModel vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = vm;

        this.AddHandler(ScheduleControl.SelectedAppointmentChangedEvent, new SelectedAppointmentChangedHandler(OnSelectedAppointmentChanged));
    }

    private void OnSelectedAppointmentChanged(object sender, SelectedAppointmentChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

But I did this just to ensure the event was getting there, ultimately I want it in the XAML.  I don't seem to have the right syntax to make it work, this is what I currently have:

```
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="ScheduleControl.SelectedAppointmentChangedEvent">
                <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="OnSelectedAppointmentChanged" TargetObject="{Binding}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

I've used this before to handle routed events, but always on the same control that generates the event.  In this case I'm trying to put it further up the tree.  What am I missing?